# What to do when alcohol is denied on a full service airline?

Tags: alcohol, in-flight-services, singapore-airlines

Recently, I was aboard a Singapore airlines flight. While booking the ticket I confirmed that food and beverages - alcohol and non alcohol - are included in the airfare. And that I was liberty to drink as much as I'd want.

However, when I requested the flight attendants for a drink (whisky), I was repeatedly ignored. There was no seat belt sign on and neither was food being served. Finally, when someone was able to get me a drink, I asked them to serve me two as they were taking a long time - this was straight out denied as they have a policy (which I couldn't look up anywhere) of only one drink at a time. This seems like a clear case of me being denied of service I was promised.

What options do I have if I don't get served alcoholic beverages on a full service flight ?

Edit : I wasn't drunk or belligerent. I was very courteous and respectful

Comment: The days when passengers could drink as much alcohol as they want are long gone, thankfully.

Comment: Why all the neg votes ? The question is clear, is going to be useful in the future and the interweb doesn't give an answer to this question.

Comment: @happybuddha I’ve not voted either way, but presumably because your question boils down to “I received poor service, what can I do?” which has the obvious answer of complain to the company/your friends/the internet. Generally nothing more you can do after receiving poor service.

Comment: @Notts90 I was hoping there was an inflight solution to this,  but clearly not.

Answer (score 13):

On all airlines, the cabin crew are there primarily for safety and secondarily to provide amenities such as food and drink.

So if the cabin crew does not confidently feel that they can provide you an alcoholic beverage because: you are drunk, are already belligerent, or that you might become so if you drink too much — they are well within their rights to deny you alcohol. Your behavior could put the whole plane at risk.

There are other reasons, including that beverage and meal service might not have started and your ringing of the call button might have taken them away from other duties so they were already annoyed by the time they came to your seat. If they don’t have the cart as part of beverage service then it’s hard for them to  safely carry multiple drinks and they might be worried you might be one of those people who will become an unhappy Buddha when drinking too much (remembering first  that alcohol is stronger and altitude and second that there will be drink service soon and you might ask for a third drink then) so they want to pace you.

You could complain to the airline company but they almost always stand behind the decisions of the crew when couched in terms of safety.

At best you might  get a refund for what you paid for the alcohol — ie $0.

P.s.  calling the cabin crew member an “air hostess” is a sure-fired way to also get ignored and underserved.

Comment: Updated the question to be clear about my state while making the request (and cabin crew)- but I can understand - there'd be no way for them to know how I'd behave after the drink. But that would be the case for any one. Wonder why alcoholic beverages are included in the service then. Certainly, the fare has considered my luggage weight allowance, sanitary needs and food and drink consumption amongst other things.

Comment: They don’t know but one safe thing is to space out the amount of drink over time so they don’t become instantly drunk. Remember that alcohol is twice as powerful at altitude.

Comment: I would like to agree with this answer, but for budget airlines they seem to believe that they're there to provide advertising and a revenue stream.  Every flight with ryanair or easyjet involves (ab)using the tannoy system to sell lottery tickets and other goods.  In addition there are multiple recent examples where people were leaving a plane in an emergency situation with luggage and high heels.